How do I do date validation in DialogFlow CX?
While getting the value for the parameter 'departure-date' for an agent in DialogFlow CX, I want to make sure that the user only enters either today's date or a future date. If not, I want to print an 'Invalid Date' message and re -prompt for an input.
I tried adding an event handler to compare the date and then route the agent accordingly, but I can't figure out how to get the current date to compare with.

Date handling has recently been significantly improved in Dialogflow CX. You can use the following system functions:

NOW current Date-Time
IS_FUTURE_DATE check if date is in the future

Additionally the sys.date-time system entity now offers a future property which may address your use case.
